# How to open email attachment in my app on android?

Tags: android, email, download, attachment, intentfilter

I want to open a specific type of file that my app can already send over email as an attachment.  I need to be able to have the android email app choose my app to download or open that specific file type.  I can't figure out how to set up an intent filter that would let me do that though.  Anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intent filters generally work based on MIME type of the file.  But if you're using a custom file format that Android's not likely to recognise, then it's not as simple.  You can maybe try using the `android:pathPattern` attribute to try and match the filename, but it's not something I've tried.

I imagine you'd use something like this in your `<activity>` tag:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Turns out I was just missing the action and category tags.  The custom mimeType worked just fine, didn't need pathPattern. If there's a way to change the action so it shows the download button instead of preview in the email app, that would be great.