# How to download *.ics file from the browser in android?

Tags: android

How to register a new MIME type in android? I am very much new to android. I need to download a *.ics file from the browser (Email attachment).but the browser response is unsupported file format.Can anyone help me ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

[How to open email attachment in my app on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037551/how-to-open-email-attachment-in-my-app-on-android)

[How to send/open email attachments from android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033818/how-to-send-open-email-attachments-from-android-app)

For [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar), that means you will need an activity with the following `<intent-filter>`:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/calendar" />
    </intent-filter>
```